# Sort an array by selecting the occurances vba

Tags: arrays, vba, sorting, solidworks

I am currently writing a macro for Solidworks using VBA. This macro sets an array with the x, y, and arctan locations of a note. I am then looking to sort array using a bubblesort method. The array is a single dimensional array and it first sets the x values, then the y and then the arctan. If there are 9 notes then 0-8 is the x values, 9-17 are the y values, and 18-26 are the arctan. This is where I am running into an issue. I need to select the range that the sort uses.

```
arrlen = arrlen - 1
ReDim Preserve vloc(arrlen - 1)
BubbleSort1 vloc
arrlen1 = arrlen1 - 1
ReDim Preserve vloc(arrlen To arrlen1)
BubbleSort1 vloc
```

Above is my code where I call up the sorts. arrlen and arrlen1 are counters for the total notes for each value.

I am getting a script out of range error on the second sort call out.

I am not against rewriting both the initial setting of the array and the sort to us a multidimensional array, but I just don't know how to properly do that.

Below is the code where I set the array.

```
Set swFirstNote = swView.GetFirstNote
Set swNote = swView.GetFirstNote
ReDim notes(notesTotalCounter)
ReDim vloc(notesTotalCounter)
i = 0
arrlen = 0
While Not swNote Is Nothing
    If swNote.GetText Like "`*" Then
        Set swAnno = swNote.GetAnnotation
        loc = swAnno.GetPosition
        Dim t As Double
        Dim x As Double
        Dim y As Double
        x = loc(0)
        y = loc(1)
        t = ArcTan2(cpX - loc(0), cpY - loc(1))
        vloc(i) = x
        i = i + 1
        arrlen = arrlen + 1
    End If
    Set swNote = swNote.GetNext
Wend

Set swFirstNote = swView.GetFirstNote
Set swNote = swView.GetFirstNote
ReDim Preserve vloc(notesTotalCounter)
i = arrlen
arrlen1 = arrlen
While Not swNote Is Nothing
    If swNote.GetText Like "`*" Then
        Set swAnno = swNote.GetAnnotation
        ReDim Preserve vloc(i)
        loc = swAnno.GetPosition
        x = loc(0)
        y = loc(1)
        t = ArcTan2(cpX - loc(0), cpY - loc(1))
        vloc(i) = y
        i = i + 1
        arrlen1 = arrlen1 + 1
    End If
    Set swNote = swNote.GetNext
Wend
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that I wrote recently to sort an array of training subjects into alphabetical order. After returning from this subroutine, I load the array into a combo box. The training subjects are listed in a priority order in a row of a worksheet, from cell C2 and to the left. The number of training subjects varies as it can be added to and deleted at various times. Here is the subroutine that gets called to create the global array strSubject() to pass to the Userform Activate event to populate the combo box.

You should be able to take the basic idea behind the sorting routine and adapt it for your code. Because all of my records are text, I use the tilde (~) to ensure the second array gets populated with the next available record alphabetically. As you are using numbers, you may want to replace the tilde in thie code with a number that is less than any possible value in your data, so if your lowest value is 1, make the comparator -1. If your lowest possible value is -i,ooo,ooo,ooo, make your comparator lower than that. If you are unsure, run a third routine to find the lowest value in your data array, subtract 1 and make that value your comparator value.

Sub Create_Alphabetical_Subject_List()

```
Dim f As Integer
Dim x As Integer: x = 1
Dim y As Integer: y = 1
Dim strTempSubject() As String

Set wss = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Internal Training Matrix")
varSubjectCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Internal Training Matrix").Range("C2", Worksheets("Internal Training Matrix").Range("C2").End(xlEnd)))

ReDim varSortedFlag(varSubjectCount)
ReDim varSorted(varSubjectCount)
ReDim strTempSubject(varSubjectCount)
ReDim strSubject(varSubjectCount)

For x = 1 To varSubjectCount
    If wss.Cells.Item(2, x + 2) <> "" And wss.Cells.Item(2, x + 2) <> "Spare" Then
        strTempSubject(x) = wss.Cells.Item(2, x + 2) ' From row 2 col 3 initially
        varSorted(x) = "~"
        varSortedFlag(x) = ""
    End If
Next x

For y = 1 To varSubjectCount
    For x = 1 To varSubjectCount
        If varSortedFlag(x) = "" And strTempSubject(x) < varSorted(y) Then
            varSorted(y) = strTempSubject(x)    ' Swap out a lower value
            f = x   ' Track which record was last copied to new array
        End If
    Next x
    strSubject(y) = varSorted(y)
    varSortedFlag(f) = "Done" ' Remove the record from future comparrisons
Next y
```

End Sub